# how can i remove an error on php when i process an xml childnodes->length

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read some XML but I have some errors when I try to get the length of the child.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/3Bjg2RjT) is an example of the XML and [here](http://pastebin.com/iE0MiFkL) is the code to process the xml.

The problem occurs sometimes when I access the length, for example in line 92.

The error is:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: backend/mantenimiento.php
Line Number: 159
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you do that

```
$terNivel = $doc->childNodes->item($x)->childNodes->item($y)->childNodes;
print_r($terNivel->length);
```

the `item($y)` has no child nodes so `item($y)->childNodes` is equal to null, so it is normal that you can not get the length.